# I wanted the free evenings for going out with friends

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-order

why do we have expressions like 'free time' , 'free afternoon' , and so on. , but we can't have 'free evenings'? What is the rule behind this?
I was also searching and I found out that although 'free' is an adjective and can come before 'noun', in this meaning it can come either after or before nouns. 
Here it means 'available', but What makes me confused most is that when we can use this adjective before and when we can use after 'noun'?

> I wanted the evenings free for going out with friends.
>
> I wanted the free evenings for going out with friends.

Comment: "free evenings" is just as possible as "free afternoons / day / etc...".

Comment: As Laure says, "free evenings" is perfectly possible, however it is little used because for many people work is 9 to 5 and so their evenings are normally free anyway.

Comment: "...but we can't have 'free evenings'" you wrote, but you don't say how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: @JavaLatte In my experience, *free evenings* are a very dear commodity for folks with school-age children :p.

Comment: @1006a: There, but for the grace of God, go I.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the word [free](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/free) to talk about not being busy, it is an adjective. You can use an adjective in two ways, with slightly different word orders:

> I want a red dress - *to **qualify** something (identify what kind of dress you are talking about)*
>   the dress is red - *to **describe** something (say something about it)*

.

> I wanted the evenings free for going out with friends.

This sentence doesn't fit either pattern, so what's going on? It makes more sense if you insert **to be** into the sentence like this:

> I wanted the evenings **to be** free for going out with friends.

You would use this version to **describe** the state that you wanted your evenings **to be**.

> I wanted the free evenings for going out with friends.

Here, you are using free as a **qualifying** adjective, so that you can say what you want to do with this category of evening.

Comment: how about?I've got no Thursdays free this term.

Comment: @MickeyMouse: I have updated my answer: Your sentence could be understood in a describing sense: "I've got no Thursdays **that are** free this term". You could also say the same thing in a qualifying sense: "I've got no free Thursdays this term".

Answer (score 1):

As JavaLatte answered you can use the first version that means:

- I wanted the evenings to be free for going out with friends.

or use the second version.

> The way this works is that normally an adjective modifying a noun goes
>   before the noun but But an adjective which has a complement cannot be
>   placed in front of the noun; it must be treated as a reduced relative
>   clause and placed after the noun.

- I wanted the evenings free for going out with friends.

> A *[**reduced relative clause**](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107)* (aka *adjective clause*) is one from which the relative pronoun and any immediately following copula have been deleted as unnecessary: ***to be*** free for going out with friends

---

> [In modern English adjectives may undergo a change of meaning when used
>   postpositively.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective)

- I'm here to find the *responsible* people.
- I'm here to find the people *responsible*.

> Used prepositively, as in the first sentence, it generally means
>   something like "trustworthy" or "reliable", but when used
>   postpositively, as in the second sentence, it probably means "at
>   fault" or "guilty" (of some misdeed known from the context). Another
>   adjective with a special postpositive meaning is proper: in phrases
>   like the town proper, Sweden proper, it means something like "strictly
>   defined".